# How I can solve a sqflite conflicting with sdk in android studio?

Tags: flutter, sdk, sqflite, dart-null-safety, pubspec

I have a problem when add sqflite to my project(flutter) to dependencies in SDK 31.0.0 and the console make like this when make run :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':sqflite:compileDebugAidl'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can following the steps in the picture to install the missing version:

> Tools - SDK Manager - SDK Tools - Show Package Details

Select the version you need, and click apply button to install it:

[image]

Comment: to solve Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2